# How can we load a board from TXT file into a two dimensional array(without rowSize and columnSize)

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a txt file and there is a board like this =>

I want to use dynamic array( with using `new` keyword).But all the example in the internet with row and column size.But I don't know row and columSize.So I must do that without columnSize and rowSize.

Comment: Please add some code you tried.

Comment: Do you have *any* knowledge of how large the board can be? 10x10? 100x100? Is it too much to allocate the max size?

Comment: So, what did you try?

Comment: I can't try even. Because columnSize and rowSize is changeable .So what can I do? @Vlav

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   ifstream fin;

   fin.open ("input1.txt");

   if ( !fin ) exit( 1 );

   int row1, col1; // Sizes needed for array

   fin >> row1 >> col1;

   int **a = new int *[row1]; 

   for ( int i = 0; i < row1; i++ ) 
   {
      a[i] = new int[col1];
   }

   for ( int i = 0; i < row1; i++ )
   {
      for ( int j = 0; j < col1; j++ )
      {
         fin >> a[i][j];
      }
   }


   // You do the same for the second array 

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While this code may answer the question, the answer may get downvoted for including only a code dump and no explanation. You should improve this answer by explaining how it works and why you did it this way. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and other guidelines in the help section for more info.

Comment: this is work but This solution doesn't accept spaces ' ' like an array element.
So if I print this ,Spaces will not show on the screen.Only show *.

Comment: I'm new so sorry for this inconvenience. Next time I will improve my answer. This question is so basic. Thank you!

Comment: Demo code is loading integer array. Instead try to load string. Good luck!

Comment: columnSize and rowSize is changeable .So what can I do?

Comment: You could optionally allocate the board as a single dimension array:  `int * a = new int[row1 * col1];`  This would guarantee that all board positions are in the same area.